# Remove file with Non-Interactive SSH Login

Tags: unix, ssh, sshpass

I'm trying to remote delete a file from a server with `sshpass`.

Using regular `ssh` works just fine:

```
ssh username@ip rm -f fullpath/file.txt
username@ip's password: ****
```

but when I try with `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p 'password' username@ip rm -f fullpath/file.txt

server answer: sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Why you don't use a public key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```sh
sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@ip rm -f fullpath/file.txt
```